# face recognition feature in a facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook, face-recognition

I'm starting to build an app for Facebook and I want to use face recognition feature in it.
Is there a way to use the face recognition feature that FB introduced last year or do I have to turn for other sites for that feature? Also, if possible, some tutorials or web sites concerning the topic would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot use the recognition feature of Facebook, but this might help you:

http://www.xarg.org/2008/07/face-detection-with-php/

Comment: I've seen that, and it is my first alternative. But I really wanted to use their feature and integrate my app with FB as much as I can. 
Thanks for answering.